# How to execute two or more executions scripts simultaneously on a same URL using WATIR

Tags: internet-explorer, automation, watir, watir-classic

I am using watir 2.0.1,currently if a script is running on url say ABC.com in one tab for IE browser and if i opens same url ABC.com in other tab or new instance of the browser then the execution will switch to this new tab open.
Because of this i am not able to execute multiple scripts/executions on same URL

Here is the code for Script1.rb in Project1,

```
require 'watir'
browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto 'https://example.com'
browser = Watir::Browser.attach(:title, /ABC Application/)
browser.button(:text,"Register").click
sleep 2
browser.text_field(:id,"First_Name").set "Script_1_FirstName"
sleep 2
browser.text_field(:id,"Last_Name").set "Script_1_LastName"
```

and so on...

While Script1 is filling the register form for ABC application in Browser instance1,at the same time(Say after Script1 Enters First Name, i will trigger Script2.rb for some basic validations of the register form page.

Here is the code for Script2.rb in Project2,

```
require 'watir'
browser1 = Watir::Browser.new
browser1.goto 'https://example.com'
browser1 = Watir::Browser.attach(:title, /ABC Application/)

//At this time Script2 will execute properly in IE Instance2 as there is
//no Register button at IE instance1(Because Script1 is already on
//Register form page) 

browser1.button(:text,"Register").click

//The movement Register form opens in IE instance2,Script1 finds same page
//elements on IE instance2 so currently Script1 is automatically start its
//execution on IE instance2 which will affect Script2 Execution.     

if(browser1.text_field(:id,"First_Name").text.include("")
puts "First name field is blank by default"
else
raise "First name field is not blank by default"

if(browser1.text_field(:id,"Last_Name").text.include("")
puts "Last name field is blank by default"
else
raise "Last name field is not blank by default"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with each script attaching to a browser, which may or may not be the one opened earlier in the script.

The line:

```
browser = Watir::Browser.attach(:title, /ABC Application/)
```

Is saying to attach to the first browser with a title that includes "ABC Application". If all of the scripts are looking for this title, they will all be attaching to the same browser.

The solution is to use the browser that was opened by the script. This should simply require deleting this `Watir::Browser.attach` line. The `browser` variable would then continue to point to the browser it opened in `browser = Watir::Browser.new`.

Comment: Its not with the same variable, i am using different projects to run these scripts.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I am misunderstanding your code example. Why would you create a new browser instance, `Watir::Browser.new`, navigate to a page and then try to attach to a browser instance `Watir::Browser.attach(:title, /ABC Application/)`?

Comment: In order to automate any web application for software testing purposes i am using the above code like create a new browser instance then attach the web application tittle then use this object to automate web page elements like radio,text field.

For example below code in script1 is for clicking radio button on a web application which has tittle as ABC Application

Script1.rb
    require 'watir'browser = Watir::Browser.new
    browser.goto 'https://example.com'
    browser = Watir::Browser.attach(:title, /ABC Application/)
    browser.radio(:id,"Test").click

Comment: But that does not explain why you need to `attach`, which I am guessing is the problem. `Watir::Browser.attach(:title, /ABC Application/)` will attached to the first browser window with that title. Depending on what page your other browsers are on, this may or may not be the same browser that was created by `browser = Watir::Browser.new`.

Comment: so whats is the solution,to run simultaneous executions without attaching the title

Comment: You should just be able to delete the `Watir::Browser.attach` line. The `browser` variable is already pointing to the newly opened window when you do `browser = Watir::Browser.new`.

Comment: When the second script(Completely in different project, means required to initialize the browser variable in order to access the web page ) runs it will open new instance and loads the same url. My question is if i have deleted Watir::Browser.attach line then how the script will identify the elements on the web page.

Comment: The second script has opened a new instance and loaded a page, therefore it is already a browser instance. It can already identify elements within its page. Both `Watir::Browser.new` and `Watir::Browser.attach` return an instance of `Watir::Browser`. The only difference is that one opens a new browser while the other looks for an existing one.

Comment: Agreed, but is there is another method we can resolve this problem.I have to execute the multiple scripts at the time simultaneously because i have time and machine constrains so i have to execute on the single machine only by running the scripts in different browser instances for same web application.

Comment: Can you create an example script with step-by-step instructions to reproduce your issue? It is very unclear where the problem is.

Comment: Hi Justin, I have edited code with example in the question description hope the problem is cleared to you

Comment: Is that the entire script1? I am still do not see why you need to use `attach` and so I am suspicious that there are more usages of this method later.